# Making equal div height even if the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make all my divs the same height even if the browser is resized. I have 4 icon boxes. each box has an icon, a title, and a description. I want to make all of them same size. that means if the highest height of the icon container div is 100px all icon holder div will be 100px. the following code is working but *if I resize the browser some time the height of the container divs is much bigger than the actual height*. what I am doing wrong? (Note the resize will only happen screen size above 767px) thanks

```
 function allSameHeight(sameSec, sameImg, sameTitle, sameDesc) {
        jQuery(sameSec).each(function () {
          let highestImg = 0;
          let highestTitle = 0;
          let highestTxt = 0;
      
          jQuery(sameSec).find(sameImg).each(function () {
              if (jQuery(this).height() > highestImg) {
                highestImg = jQuery(this).height();
              }
            });
          jQuery(sameSec).find(sameTitle).each(function () {
              if (jQuery(this).height() > highestTitle) {
                highestTitle = jQuery(this).height();
              }
            });
      
          jQuery(sameSec).find(sameDesc).each(function () {
              if (jQuery(this).height() > highestTxt) {
                highestTxt = jQuery(this).height();
              }
            });
      
          if (jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
            jQuery(sameSec).find(sameImg).css("min-height", highestImg);
            jQuery(sameSec).find(sameTitle).css("min-height", highestTitle);
            jQuery(sameSec).find(sameDesc).css("min-height", highestTxt);
          } else {
            jQuery(sameSec).find(sameImg).css("min-height", "auto");
            jQuery(sameSec).find(sameTitle).css("min-height", "auto");
            jQuery(sameSec).find(sameDesc).css("min-height", "auto");
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: It looks like [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) is your friend ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a class to all four items. I've used `myItem` for instance.

```js
const setHeights = () => {
  let highestHeight = 0;
  //Loop through all elements and get the highest height
  $('.myItem').each((index, element) => {
    if($(element).outerHeight() > highestHeight) {
      highestHeight = $(element).outerHeight();
    }
  });
  //Set the height of all elements to highest
  $('.myItem').height(highestHeight);
};

$(window).resize(() => {
  //Run each time window is resized
  setHeights();
});
```

```css
.myItem {
width: 25%;
color: white;
float: right;
}

.one {
background: red;
}

.two {
background: blue;
}

.three {
background: purple;
}

.four {
background: orange;
}

h3 {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<button onclick="setHeights()">Make them equal</button>
</div>

<div class="myItem one">
<h3>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
</h3>
</div>

<div class="myItem two">
<h3>
bbbbbbbb
</h3>
</div>

<div class="myItem three">
<h3>
ccccccccccccccc
ccccccccc
</h3>
</div>

<div class="myItem four">
<h3>
ddddddddddddddd
ddddddddddd
ddddddddddddd
ddddddddddddddd
ddddddddddddddddd
</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: It is outputting 0 all the time.  can you please recheck the code

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my code. Now it's working. Try the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For this case there are multiple approaches, I'll mention the two most common (in my opinion):

1. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp
2. Using flexbox: https://moderncss.dev/equal-height-elements-flexbox-vs-grid/